# Parallel numbering in columns

Tags: paracol

I have a bilingual text in two columns using `paracol`. I want to number them in parallel while using `switchcolumn` commands, as shown below. How can I do this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}
I want this,
\begin{paracol}{2} 
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Item.
        \item Item

\end{enumerate}
\switchcolumn
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Item.
    \item Item 2.
\end{enumerate}
\end{paracol}
which is tedious.

\vspace{2cm}
I do not want this:
\begin{paracol}{2} 
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Item.
    \switchcolumn
    \item Item.
    \switchcolumn*

    \item Item.
    \switchcolumn
    \item Item 2.
\end{enumerate}
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

======= Edit =====

The problem with the first is that, when the second column has a much longer text, the next numbers in the two columns do not start at the same level, as shown below:
[image]

I want the two lists to be always at the same level.

Comment: Your code itself generates the output as above image.  Can you be more specific on your query, or I misunderstood something?

Comment: Maybe a table is an option for this?

Comment: The problem with table/longtable is that, my list will occupy a whole book and neither table nor longtable manage this well; paracol seems to be the best choice.

Comment: And I want numbered lists on both columns... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an all-automatic solution, but it seems to work:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{paracol, calc, blindtext}

\globalcounter{enumi}
\newcommand{\switchenum}{\setcounter{enumi}{\theenumi-1}\switchcolumn}



    \begin{document}

\vspace{2cm}

Some text.

\begin{paracol}{2} 
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Item left
    \switchenum
    \item \blindtext

    \switchcolumn*

    \item Second Item left
    \switchenum
    \item Second Item right
\end{enumerate}
\end{paracol}

Just to look for sideeffects:

\begin{paracol}{2} 
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Item left
    \switchenum
    \item Item right
    \switchcolumn

    \item Second Item left
    \switchenum
    \item Second Item right
\end{enumerate}\setcounter{enumi}{0}
\end{paracol}


\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of result]

Comment: Works for me to, but I've changed the command a bit to allow for custom enumerate labels `\newcommand{\switchenum}{\setcounter{enumi}{\arabic{enumi}-1}\switchcolumn}`

Answer (score 1):

Each column has separate `enumi` counters, but `\begin{enumerate}` only sets one of them to zero.  One can use `\synccounter{enumi}` to fix this.

Note that some packages use different counters than `enumi`, `enumii`, etc.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}
\noindent I do not want this:\setcounter{enumi}{6}%
\begin{paracol}{2} 
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Item.
    \switchcolumn
    \item Item.
    \switchcolumn*
    \item Item.
    \switchcolumn
    \item Item 2.
\end{enumerate}
\end{paracol}
I want this:
\begin{paracol}{2} 
\begin{enumerate}\synccounter{enumi}
    \item Item.
    \switchcolumn
    \item Item.
    \switchcolumn*
    \item Item.
    \switchcolumn
    \item Item 2.
\end{enumerate}
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]