# Problems aligning left and right parbox

Tags: vertical-alignment, expex, parbox

I [previously asked a similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357317/problems-aligning-left-and-right-columns-in-paracol), but that was related to `paracol`. This question is related to `parbox`, so I think the solution will be a bit different.

As you can see, the two `parbox`es don't line up as I want. The red and blue lines should be exactly even.

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{microtype}  
\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{FrankRuehl}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Times New Roman}

\lingset{
    everygla=\Large,
    everyglb=\scriptsize\englishfont,
    everyglc=\scriptsize\englishfont,
    glwordalign=center,
    glhangindent=0em,
    glrightskip=0pt,
   }

\usepackage{ifoddpage}

\newcommand{\swapboxes}[2]% #1 = wide text, #2 = narrow text
{\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{\checkoddpage
 \ifoddpageoroneside
   \parbox[t]{.71\textwidth}{#1}\hfill\parbox[t]{.26\textwidth}{#2}%
 \else
   \parbox[t]{.26\textwidth}{#2}\hfill\parbox[t]{.71\textwidth}{#1}%
 \fi}}% this \swapboxes macro forces the parboxes to switch sides every odd page

\begin{document}

\swapboxes{\exdisplay\begingl
  \gla אאאא בבבב גגגג דדדד אא בב גג דד אאאא בב גגגג דדד אאאא בבבבב גג דדדד אא בבבב גגגגג דדד אאאא בבבב גגגג דדדד אא בב גג דד אאאא //

  \glb aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa  //

  \glc aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa //

\endgl \xe}{\exdisplay\footnotesize\textenglish{Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is the end} \xe}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a `\strut` before going to `\footnotesize` on the left text, as in `\exdisplay\strut\footnotesize\textenglish{...}`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{microtype}  
\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{FrankRuehl}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Times New Roman}

\lingset{
    everygla=\Large,
    everyglb=\scriptsize\englishfont,
    everyglc=\scriptsize\englishfont,
    glwordalign=center,
    glhangindent=0em,
    glrightskip=0pt,
   }

\usepackage{ifoddpage}

\newcommand{\swapboxes}[2]% #1 = wide text, #2 = narrow text
{\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{\checkoddpage
 \ifoddpageoroneside
   \parbox[t]{.71\textwidth}{#1}\hfill\parbox[t]{.26\textwidth}{#2}%
 \else
   \parbox[t]{.26\textwidth}{#2}\hfill\parbox[t]{.71\textwidth}{#1}%
 \fi}}% this \swapboxes macro forces the parboxes to switch sides every odd page

\begin{document}

\swapboxes{\exdisplay\begingl
  \gla אאאא בבבב גגגג דדדד אא בב גג דד אאאא בב גגגג דדד אאאא בבבבב גג דדדד אא בבבב גגגגג דדד אאאא בבבב גגגג דדדד אא בב גג דד אאאא //

  \glb aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa  //

  \glc aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa //

\endgl \xe}{\exdisplay\strut\footnotesize\textenglish{Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is the end} \xe}

\end{document}
```

[image]