# Synchronized paracol columns don't align

Tags: vertical-alignment, paracol

I've been confounded for a while about an issue with `paracol`. When one uses the synchronization feature `*` the columns are supposed to synchronize, which they do even in my simple MWE below. What they **don't** do, however, is align perfectly with each other. The first line does but subsequent paragraphs don't.

I've asked a [related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357317/problems-aligning-left-and-right-columns-in-paracol) before, but now I'm not really asking for my specific example but rather in general. Why is this happening, and is there a generic fix?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[twoside]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{paracol}
    \twosided[pc]

\columnratio{0.71}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.0em}

\begin{document}
    \begin{paracol}{2}
        \begin{leftcolumn*}\noindent
            \lipsum[1]
        \end{leftcolumn*}
        \begin{rightcolumn}\noindent\footnotesize
            \lipsum[2]
        \end{rightcolumn}

        \begin{leftcolumn*}\noindent
            \lipsum[3]
        \end{leftcolumn*}
        \begin{rightcolumn}\noindent\footnotesize
            \lipsum[4]
        \end{rightcolumn}

        \begin{leftcolumn*}\noindent
            \lipsum[5]
        \end{leftcolumn*}
        \begin{rightcolumn}\noindent\footnotesize
            \lipsum[6]
        \end{rightcolumn}

        \begin{leftcolumn*}\noindent
            \lipsum[7]
        \end{leftcolumn*}
        \begin{rightcolumn}\noindent\footnotesize
            \lipsum[8]
        \end{rightcolumn}

    \end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

As you can see below, the left and right columns don't align perfectly. Is there a generic solution to this problem so that no matter what you or I put in the opposing columns the top lines will align?

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boxes don't align along the first baseline but along their real top. So you need to ensure that the first line has identical height:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[twoside]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{paracol}
    \twosided[pc]

\columnratio{0.71}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.0em}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\mystrut{\rule{0pt}{14pt}}  
\begin{document}
    \begin{paracol}{2}
        \begin{leftcolumn*}\noindent
            \lipsum[1]
        \end{leftcolumn*}
        \begin{rightcolumn}\noindent\footnotesize
            \lipsum[2]
        \end{rightcolumn}

        \begin{leftcolumn*}[]\noindent\mystrut
            \tikz[overlay]\draw[red](0,0)--++(20,0);xxx %\lipsum[3]
        \end{leftcolumn*}
        \begin{rightcolumn}\noindent\mystrut
            xxx %\lipsum[4]
        \end{rightcolumn}

        \begin{leftcolumn*}\noindent\mystrut
           \tikz[overlay]\draw[red](0,0)--++(20,0);xxx %\lipsum[3]
            \lipsum*[5]
        \end{leftcolumn*}
        \begin{rightcolumn}\noindent\mystrut\footnotesize            
            \lipsum*[6]
        \end{rightcolumn}

        \begin{leftcolumn*}\noindent\mystrut
           \tikz[overlay]\draw[red](0,0)--++(20,0);xxx %\lipsum[3]
            \lipsum*[7]
        \end{leftcolumn*}
        \begin{rightcolumn}\noindent\mystrut\footnotesize           
            \lipsum*[8]
        \end{rightcolumn}

    \end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

[image]